# how to set innodb_strict_mode = 0 in phpmyadmin or xammp

Tags: mysql, sql

How can to set innodb_strict_mode = 0 in phpmyadmin because i'm having a problem in MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB.

I got this error when i set 96 entities in my table with a random datatypes consisting of int, varchar, text and date.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_student`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_student` (
  `s_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ss_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `snext` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdbirth` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saddress` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `szcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scontact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sctship` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scivilstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spbirth` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdisability` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s4psno` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spwdid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `srappsship` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `srappnas` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `sbos` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssskills` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `stwinterest` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssdfile` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgfname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgmname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sglname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgnext` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sglstatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgeduc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgcontact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgaddress` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgoccu` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgcompany` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sffname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfmname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sflname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfnext` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sflstatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfeduc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfcontact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfaddress` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfoccu` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sfcompany` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smfname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smmname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smlname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smnext` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smlstatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smeduc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smcontact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smaddress` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `smoccu` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smcompany` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `snsibling` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spcyincome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spschname` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `spsaddress` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `spstype` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spscourse` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spsyrlvl` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spsgwa` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spsraward` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `spsdawardrceive` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `scsintend` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `scsadd` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `scschooltype` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sccourse` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sccourseprio` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scsyrlvl` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spass` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdsprc` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdsprcstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdspgm` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdspgmstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdspcr` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdspcrstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdstbytpic` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdstbytpicstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdsbrgyin` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdsbrgyinstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdscef` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdscefstat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdspsa` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdspsastat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sdsobr` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sdsobrstat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `student_profile_image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_added_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_applied_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_verification_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_email_verify` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_account_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_grant_stat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `s_scholar_stat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `s_scholarship_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Here are my entities in my table. I tried to change something to data types and number I can't change and nothing happens.

Comment: split the table in 2 or 3 tables, there are limits that you have to comply

Comment: I can't split it to 2 to 3 tables because my system is already built and i just only want to add 2 to 3 entities in the database

Comment: then you need to change the types of varchar to text, as this is saved external and will not cout to the row size. the row size can not be increased

Comment: Ok i will do this i will update you if you're solution works.

Comment: @Longkoy732    Is there a reason for 4 columns with fname as a part of the column name?  There a few of these columns that seem to be repeating, Is anyone else surprised by the absence of any PRIMARY key?  No PRIMARY key usually equals slow response time.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck Thank you very much for your comment, I find some downside to my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [innodb_strict_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_strict_mode) to OFF with the SQL statement

```
SET innodb_strict_mode=OFF;
```

But that's kind of like catching and ignoring exceptions: all you're doing is concealing serious errors from your application.

The row-length limit in MySQL / MariaDB / InnoDB is a *hard* limit. If you try to exceed it your INSERT and UPDATE statements will fail.

You said your requirement is to extend a table with a few extra columns. And, in doing that you've hit the row-length limit. It happens (Remarks about the programmer who came before you removed ... this is a family-friendly web site.)

What can you do?

**An easy fix**: Change the table's CHARSET from `utf8mb4` to `utf8`. That way you need three, rather than four bytes, per VARCHAR character. But `utf8` is deprecated: it can't represent emojis and some other characters.

**Next possible fix**. Identify the VARCHAR columns that don't need Unicode. `sdbirth`? `s_verification_code`? `student_profile_image`? Declare those colums with

```
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin
```

If you make this change to `s_verification_code` and `student_profile_image` you'll save 600 bytes-- one byte per character rather than four, for two 100-character columns. That's enough that you can probably finish this task and pass off this table to your (unsuspecting) successor.

**Another idea** Change some of your VARCHAR() columns to TEXT columns. But beware! this slows down queries.  If your application has mostly `SELECT *` queries in it you probably don't want to do this. If it has mostly `SELECT column, column, column` queries this is probably OK.

**A slightly harder fix**:  Reduce the width of some of your fields. Does every personal name have to be stored as `VARCHAR(50)`? Will `VARCHAR(30)` do the trick? Do you need 10 characters for gender?  Can you represent date-of-birth with a DATE datatype? It will take [three bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time) rather than the 40 (VARCHAR(10)) it now uses.

**The right fix** Rework your app so some of that data (contact information, etc) for each student lives in different tables.  Or, create a new table for the new data you're adding.